# OnStartCommand/OnCreate not called

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I've created a service to run SignalR in a foreground service.  When I start the service I get no errors but OnCreate and OnStartCommand are never called.  Yes, I checked the ForeGround_Service in the manifest.  The code I use to start the service is:

```
    public void StartForegroundServiceComapt<SignalRSrv>(Context context, Bundle args = null) where SignalRSrv : Service
    {
        var intent = new Intent(context, typeof(SignalRSrv));
        if (args != null)
        {
            intent.PutExtras(args);
        }

        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            context.StartForegroundService(intent);
        }
        else
        {
            context.StartService(intent);
        }
    }
```

The service code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Acr.UserDialogs;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Java.Lang;
using Java.Util.Concurrent;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Transports;


namespace MyService_Android
{
    public class SignalRSrv : Service
    {
        private bool InstanceFieldsInitialized = false;

        private void InitializeInstanceFields()
        {
            mBinder = new LocalBinder(this);
        }

        private Handler mHandler; // to display Toast message
        private IBinder mBinder; // Binder given to clients
        private SignalRSingleton mInstance;
        internal const string MY_ACTION = "MY_ACTION";

        public SignalRSrv()
        {
            if (!InstanceFieldsInitialized)
            {
                InitializeInstanceFields();
                InstanceFieldsInitialized = true;
            }

        }

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            mInstance = SignalRSingleton.getInstance();
            mHandler = new Handler(Looper.MainLooper);
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            mInstance.mHubConnection.Stop();
            base.OnDestroy();
        }


        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            Bundle bundlee = intent.GetBundleExtra("TheBundle");
            startSignalR();
            return mBinder;
        }

        private void startSignalR()
        {
            mInstance.setmHubConnection();
            mInstance.setHubProxy();

            try
            {
                // Connect the client to the hup
                mInstance.mHubConnection.Start();
                // Set the event handler
                mInstance.WireUp();

            }
            catch (System.Exception e) when (e is InterruptedException || e is ExecutionException)
            {
                //opps
                var x = 1;
                return;
            }

        }

        public async void showMessage(string message)
        {

            var result = await UserDialogs.Instance.ConfirmAsync(new ConfirmConfig
            {
                Message = "Text Message from OML: " + System.Environment.NewLine + message,
                OkText = "Ok",

            });
            if (result)
            {
                // do something
                var x = message;
            }
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            if (intent.Action.Equals(Constants.ACTION_START_SERVICE))
            {
                if (InstanceFieldsInitialized)
                {

                    //Log.Info(TAG, "OnStartCommand: The service is already running.");
                }
                else
                {
                    //Log.Info(TAG, "OnStartCommand: The service is starting.");
                    startSignalR();
                    RegisterForegroundService();
                    InstanceFieldsInitialized = true;
                }
            }
            else if (intent.Action.Equals(Constants.ACTION_STOP_SERVICE))
            {
                StopSelf();
                InstanceFieldsInitialized = false;

            }
            else if (intent.Action.Equals(Constants.ACTION_RESTART))
            {

            }

            // This tells Android not to restart the service if it is killed to reclaim resources.
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        void RegisterForegroundService()
        {
            var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .SetContentTitle(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.app_name))
                .SetContentText(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.notification_text))
                .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.alert_box)
                .SetOngoing(true)
                .Build();


            // Enlist this instance of the service as a foreground service
            StartForeground(Constants.SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
        }

    }
    public class LocalBinder : Binder
    {
        private readonly SignalRSrv outerInstance;

        public LocalBinder(SignalRSrv outerInstance)
        {
            this.outerInstance = outerInstance;
        }

        public virtual SignalRSrv Service
        {
            get
            {
                // Return this instance of SignalRService so clients can call public methods
                return outerInstance;
            }
        }
    }
```

I set breakpoints in the debugger and they never get hit.  The icon set in the `RegisterForegroundService()` is never shown (not surprised as the service is not instantiated).

Comment: Hi, What do you mean before the code is working?

Comment: The SignalR code was tested independently and works fine.  Now I want to run it as a service.

Comment: Okey, do you set breakpoints in OnCreate() of Service, and check whether it can be work.

Comment: I do and they never hit.

Answer (score 3):

Well, this turned out to be a simple answer (aren't they all?).  I added `[Service]` to the top of the service class, IE;

```
[Service]
public class SignalRSrv : Service
{
   ..... all my other stuff .....
}
```

It now hits the OnCreate and OnStartCommand as expected.
No reason to wonder why I drink ....